# SQL Nearest Past Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Hi i have an issue on handling some data on SQL, and returning some values by the nearest date. I have two Tables:

Table 1

```
    ID       Content         Date
--------------------------------------------
   123    X              2013-11-18 
   123    ZE             2013-11-29  
   233    YX             2013-12-30
   233    XX             2013-12-28  
   444    Z              2014-02-24
```

Table 2

```
 ID       Value         Validation Date
--------------------------------------------
   123    0.54              2013-11-11
   123    0.42              2013-11-18 
   123    0.32              2013-11-27 
   233    1.2               2013-12-4 
   233    1.1               2013-12-28 
   233    1.0               2013-12-29 
   444    4                 2014-02-11
   444    3                 2014-02-15
   444    2                 2014-02-23
```

The output that i pretend is something like:

```
    ID       Content         Date          Value      Validation Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   123    X              2013-11-18       0.42         2013-11-18
   123    ZE             2013-11-29       0.32         2013-11-27
   233    YX             2013-12-30       1.0          2013-12-29
   233    XX             2013-12-28       1.1          2013-12-28
   444    Z              2014-02-24       2            2014-02-23
```

So i would like to return back the value where the validation date is the nearest to the date (where the validation date has to be always smaller than the date). Can you please help me? The ID in table 1 and 2 is not unique.

Comment: why you shown first two columns under one name? it's one column or the first one is not a column and it's record number or...waht ...clarify it ?

Comment: ID's are the 123, 233 and 444. The numbers on the side are the records number and i don't pretend to work with them unless they are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Content, [Date], Value, [Validation Date]
FROM (
   SELECT t1.ID, Content, [Date], Value, [Validation Date], 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID, Content 
                             ORDER BY DATEDIFF(d, [Validation Date], [Date])) AS rn
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND [Validation Date] <= [Date] 
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` is used to track the record with the smallest `[Date]` -`[Validation Date]` difference per (`ID`, `Content`) pair of values.

Comment: Only return 1 ID on table 1. And on table 1 i have more than 1 equal ID. I edited the question.

Comment: @RVeloso In that case just change the `PARTITION BY` clause by adding `Content` as well. See the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is correlation. Something like that.

```
SELECT a.id, a.content, a.date,
       (SELECT TOP 1 b.value, b.validate
        FROM table2 b
        WHERE b.id=a.id
        ORDER BY b.validate DESC) from table1 a
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.content, 
       a.date, 
       b.valu, 
       b.validationdate 
FROM (select tt.id, 
       tt.content, 
       tt.date,
       row_number() over(partition by tt.id order by tt.date desc) rn
     from table1 tt) a
JOIN (select t.id, 
       t.content, 
       t.date, 
       t.valu, 
       t.validationdate,
       row_number() over(partition by t.id order by t.validationdate desc) rn
     from table2 t) b
on a.id=b.id and a.rn=b.rn
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that for each a.ID it returns only the b.validationdate and b.result correspoding to the most recent a.Date.

Comment: but in desired output I see you wanted the most recent validation dates

Comment: i edited know, because id's are not unique. I want the most recent validation date taking account the date from each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use `outer apply`:

```
select t1.id, t1.content, t1.date, t2.value, t2.validdate
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (SELECT TOP 1 t2.value, t2.validdate
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
        ORDER BY t2.validdate DESC
     ) t2;
```